# Setting the data-binding value in polymer that was obtained from a promise

Tags: data-binding, promise, polymer, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the schedule data in JSON format, from the server and use that to render the schdule using a dom-repeat.

The code works fine if I hard-code the JSON, but if I set it using fetch, it does not work.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="xl-schedule">
<template>

<h1> Excel Schedule </h1>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{schedule}}">
    <div># <span>{{index}}</span></div>
    <div>Event name: <span>{{item.name}}</span></div>
    <div>Date: <span>{{item.date}}</span></div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'xl-schedule',
  ready: function() {

    // this.schedule = 
    // [
    //   {
    //     "name": "Event1",
    //     "date": "5/10/2016"
    //   },

    //   {
    //     "name": "Event2",
    //     "date": "5/10/2016"
    //   },

    //   {
    //     "name": "Event3",
    //     "date": "5/10/2016"
    //   }
    // ];

    fetch('resources/schedule.json').
    then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).
    then(function (response) {
      this.schedule = response;
      console.log("response",JSON.stringify(response));
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("err",err);
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried binding `this` to the second `then` callback function or using an arrow function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Alan pointed out, in your second `then` callback:

```
then(function(response) {
  this.schedule = response; // this === window
})
```

`this` does not refer to your Polymer object. The callback is invoked outside your Polymer object's context, where `this` is not defined. In non-[strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) mode, that results in `this` defaulting to the global object, which is the `window`, so you're actually setting `window.schedule`. You can verify that with [`console.log(this)` in the callback](https://plnkr.co/edit/yUGzdieAQLYhW5sQWAl8?p=preview). MDN provides a good [reference on `this` in regards to function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

Arrow functions (in ES6) don't have that problem, and `this` would be bound to the enclosing context's `this` (the Polymer object):

```
then(response => this.schedule = response) // this === Polymer obj
```

Assuming you're using ES5 (or prefer not to use an [ES6-to-ES5 transpiler](https://babeljs.io/)), you can set the `schedule` property of your Polymer object by passing to your callback a reference to your Polymer object instead of using `this` there:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  ready: function() {
    var self = this; // this === Polymer obj
    fetch(...)
      .then(function(response) {
        self.schedule = response;
      });
  }
});
```

Note you could prevent `this` from defaulting to the global object by declaring `"use strict"`. This would cause `this` to stay `undefined`, which would cause a helpful (fail-fast) error when you accidentally assign to `this.schedule` with an unintentional `this`:

```
"use strict";
Polymer({
  ...
  ready: function() {
    fetch(...)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.schedule = response; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'schedule' of undefined 
      });
  }
});
```

Here's an ES5 demo: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l3DBeVhLNHYHvgd5wNIP?p=preview)