# Polymer: how to bind an element's property to a promise result?

Tags: data-binding, promise, polymer, polymer-1.0

Let's say I have this element:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <auth-service is-authorized="{{isAuthorized}}"></auth-service>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',

      properties: {
        isAuthorized: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      },

      ready: function () {
       if (this.isAuthorized) doStuff()
       else dontDoStuff()
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And this child auth-service element:

```
<dom-module id="auth-service">
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'auth-service',

      properties: {
        isAuthorized: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      },

      ready: function () {
        var self = this
        self.fetchAuthorization()
          .then(function () {
            self.set('isAuthorized', true)
          })
          .catch(function () {
            self.set('isAuthorized', false)
          })
      },

      fetchAuthorization: function () {
        //I know this is silly, but it's for the sake of the example
        if (!localStorage.authorization) return Promise.reject('Unauthorized')
        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.authorization))
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I ensure that my-element's ready callback will be called only when the 'fetchAuthorization' promise in the auth-service's ready callback is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Add an [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers) to the isAuthorized property.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <auth-service is-authorized="{{isAuthorized}}"></auth-service>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',

      properties: {
        isAuthorized: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false,
          observer: '_authorizationChanged'
        }
      },

      _authorizationChanged: function () {
       if (this.isAuthorized) doStuff()
       else dontDoStuff()
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: This won't necessarily resolve the issue though as Polymer won't have scope of the promise result. See: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4757  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975238/setting-the-data-binding-value-in-polymer-that-was-obtained-from-a-promise